# Keep relational database structure in solr index?

Tags: mysql, database, solr, full-text-search

I was able to import data through solr DIH.

In my database I have 4 tables:

```
threads: id, user_id, country_id

tags: id

thread_tag_map: thread_id, tag_id

countries: id

posts: id, thread_id
```

I want each document in solr to consist of:

```
thread_id
tag_id
country_id
post_id
```

For example:

```
thread_id: 1
tag_id: 23
tag_id: 34
country_id: 43
post_id: 4
post_id: 23
post_id: 23
```

How should I map it?

I haven't been able to configure data-config.xml for this. I have followed the DIH tutorial without success.

Here is my schema.xml:

```
<schema name="example" version="1.2">
  <types>
    <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true"/>
    <fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="uuid" class="solr.UUIDField" indexed="true" />
    <fieldType name="text_rev" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory" withOriginal="true"
           maxPosAsterisk="3" maxPosQuestion="2" maxFractionAsterisk="0.33"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="stopwords.txt"
                enablePositionIncrements="true"
                />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
 </types>


 <fields>
   <field name="id" type="uuid" indexed="true" stored="true" default="NEW"/>
   <field name="threads.title" type="text_rev" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="posts.body" type="text_rev" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*id" type="int" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
 </fields>

<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>

 <defaultSearchField>posts.body</defaultSearchField>

 <solrQueryParser defaultOperator="OR"/>
</schema>
```

Comment: hasnt anyone already done this and could give me some help??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you just want to define these fields:

thread_id

tag_id

country_id

post_id

as indexed 'string' fields in schema.xml. post_id should be multi-valued="true". See the default schema.xml files for formatting guidelines. Or...

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml

The only tricky thing here is actually querying the database, not configuring solr. Just write a JOIN query where you can get all of the ID's you need and use a solr client library for your language to build a simple datastruction, eg (json-y):

```
[{"thread_id":"1",
  "tag_id":"14",
  "country_id":"2",
  "post_id":["5",
             "7",
             "18"
            ]
},...and more...]
```

Since Solr isn't a RDBMS, you'll have to fake your searches by either doing multiple queries or using subqueries. Another option might be using Solr to retrieve your thread or post with a full-text search, and then using an ID from there to run a MySQL query that will get you everything else you need.